# Typescript, type of child of abstract class, cannot create an instance of an abstract class

Tags: typescript

So let's have some schema.

```
abstract class Animal{}
Dog extends Animal{}
Cat extends Animal{}

const instanceMap : Map<string, type of Animal> = new Map();

instanceMap.set('cat',Cat);

instanceMap.set('dog',Dog );

const dogClass = new instanceMap.get('dog');
```

At this point I have *Cannot create an instance of an abstract class*

So how could I possibly solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type Class<T> = new (...args: unknown[]) => T

abstract class AbstractClass {
  method() {
    return 'Abstract'
  }
}

class A extends AbstractClass {}

class B extends AbstractClass {
  method() {
    return 'B'
  }
}

function factoryMethod(flag: boolean): Class<AbstractClass> {
  return flag ? A : B
}

console.log(new (factoryMethod(true))().method())
console.log(new (factoryMethod(false))().method())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the a cast `as typeof Dog` when calling `new`:

```typescript
abstract class Animal{};
class Dog extends Animal{};
class Cat extends Animal{};

const instanceMap : Map<string, typeof Animal> = new Map();

instanceMap.set('cat',Cat);

instanceMap.set('dog',Dog );

const dogClass = new (instanceMap.get('dog') as typeof Dog);
```

Cast is needed, because, from type-checker perspective, you could have assigned `Cat` into `'dog'` key as well.

Comment: I don't know about the type that I will get, it was just an example.
But  I don't know the type

Comment: Perhaps you have to use different approach - make a static factory function on each type. Something like `Dog.create(): Animal`. I cannot think of a way to do that with `new` alone right now.